# Greyed out resources - xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" and xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, androidx, android-cardview

Resources working on other XML layouts on certain layouts
are grayed out, inaccessible

[image]

This is causing some widgets not to work -  Error **Android resource linking failed** on every card-view widget

[image]

**This is the Build output**

Build failed
:app:processDebugResources
app/src/main/res/layout/bill_payment.xml
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed
Android resource linking failed

**This is the Event Log**

13:02   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\acer\Downloads.ankApp\BankApp

13:02   Gradle build failed in 24 s 131 ms

14:30   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\acer\Downloads.ankApp\BankApp

14:32   Gradle build failed in 2 m 13 s 786 ms

Comment: It means that they are not being used anymore. You can remove them. If you're sure those are being used in that file. Then it's probably cache issue.

Comment: How do I go about it, please help

Comment: The actual error message will be on right of the screen you just posted. It tells you which resource linking failed.

Comment: 14:30 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\acer\Downloads\.ankApp\BankApp

14:32 Gradle build failed in 2 m 13 s 786 ms

There it is

Comment: Can you please post full error in your question? and instead of images please post it as a text.

Comment: I have added the responses being given ..... maybe it can help u help me

Comment: Event log seems incomplete. Please try and click on `Android resource linking failed` message on left and see on the right if you can get more info.

Comment: Also it would be good if you post your layout file code instead of an image.

Comment: If I click on the left, nothing is changing on the right, but on the XML file it points to wherever I used the androidx card-view widget, which seems ok syntactically, except the greyed out xmls resources

Comment: The full xml code is too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232172/discussion-between-mayur-gajra-and-craig-mlambo).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they are greyed out simply means that those items are not being used in your layout. You can remove them.

As far as the 'resource linking failed' error, that could be due to a number of reasons in your XML. It could be caused by having the the code below twice in an XML in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Take a close look at the error logging to try to determine which specific XML file is causing the error.

Also, the error could be caused by upgrading the support libraries to 28 and above without having your `compileSdkVersion` set to 28 or higher.

Comment: I have checked the drawable folder XML files, and they seem ok.
But I did update some support libraries, how do I resolve the error.

Comment: If you updated some support libraries, then make sure that the compileSdkVersion in your  app's build.gradle file is set to 28 or above.

Comment: Yeah it is set to properly.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

Comment: Then I think you need to share the details of the gradle build failure, there doesn't appear to be enough detail to solve it.